# Is there any short way to build customised widest table reports in laravel

Tags: laravel, report, reporting

Is there any short way to build customised widest table reports in Laravel

I am developing a system that needs too many reports like ytd products (40+) and employee (85+) sale reports In the table heading product name and in rows employee name and sold qty.

Comment: This question is very hard to understand, can you please try to edit the question to provide more clarity as to what you mean by `widest table reports` and ` ytd products (40+) and employee (85+) sale reports`. As someone not familiar with your issue those statements are very hard to understand. Perhaps you can provide an example via code?

Comment: Widest table mean i have approximately 40+ Products name in columns and 85 rows of employees i want to adjust this table on print paper using html css design.